# Recommended way for using GStreamer with Qt and QML?

Tags: qt, qml, gstreamer, rtp, qmediaplayer

Because of display up to 4 UDP/RTP streams in different modes (single / dual / quad) I first decided to use GStreamer. It works but it is not easy to handle and I can not switch between viewing modes during runtime. To solve that issue I want to use Qt (5.12.4) with QML.
I read a lot about the integration of GStreamer in Qt (QGStreamer, QMediaPlayer), different GStreamer plugins (qmlglsink) and so on. At the end of the day I always end by the QMediaPlayer which integrates since Qt 5.12.x a gst-pipeline element.
I realized a Qt-QML application that show 4 UDP/RTP streams as a kind of preview and when I choose one of this previews it changes to full screen mode. A further tap on the full screen image changes back to preview mode.
BUT the performance is not really satisfied. Either one ore two previews are frozen and when I tap them the full screen is working or the preview is running and the full screen is frozen.
This leads me to the questions:
Is there a performance issue with my embedded device? -> I will check that soon. I can exclude a bandwith problem because only GStreamer works.
Is MediaPlayer with gst-pipeline the right way?
Are there other solutions with more performance using Qt with QML?

Thanks.